# Hyperledger Fabric with SoftHSM2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, softhsm

Hi I have been trying to get Hyperledger Fabric  (v2.0.1) to connect to SoftHSM2 (v2.5.0), but haven't been successful at that. The main purpose is to create a secret key for symmetric encryption/decryption and securely store the key inside the SoftHSM2. I plan to send unencrypted data from the Fabric smart contract to be encrypted by SoftHSM2 and send back to smart contract to be stored on blockchain ledger. Likewise, I plan to send encrypted data from blockchain to be decrypted by SoftHSM2 and unencrypted data back to smart contract then the users.

My issue is when I package my chaincode and invoke smart contract method, Fabric is not able to find the file with .so extension. In my case, the file is libsofhsm2.so. I've tested my code outside of Fabric to make sure that key generation, encryption, and decryption functions work.

Should I try to package Fabric chaincode manually into the .tar.gz file? Would that be an correct approach? I first thought that Fabric smart contract would be able to locate external file on my computer but maybe I was wrong? I have also looked into configuring Fabric to use PKCS11 but wasn't successful (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/dev-setup/build.html?highlight=softhsm2). I thought that this configuration is for Fabric to store user private keys in SoftHSM2 but all I want to store is a secret key which is separate from this. I don't know if this is relevant but the smart contract is written in Javascript instead of Go.

Any help or suggestion would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have set it up for Fabric Integration Test, but the conclusion is that SoftHSM2 was applied through PKCS11 instead of SW in configuration of peer or orderer. I understood this as being provided for HSM testing and thought of it as a module that provided crypto algorithms.

Comment: First of all, your biggest problem, where you can't find the .so file on the chaincode(smart contract), is that the chaincode itself runs in a new sandboxed virtual environment (the Docker container). To solve this, you need to plant the .so file in your chaincode base image set in the fabric peer.

Comment: @myeongkilkim Thank you for your suggestion. Can you please expand what it means to plant the .so file and which file(s) specifically I would need to make these changes on? Thank you.

Comment: The chaincode in the fabric is operated as a docker image/container unit, and the management entity is the peer. In other words, after the chaincode installed in the peer is deployed to the channel, the peer opens its own chaincode in the form of a docker container. This is a general sandbox environment, and code is not run in a peer, but in a separate virtual environment. This work has several advantages, such as that it does not affect the peer if a problem occurs in the process of executing the code.

Comment: In this process, the chaincode is created based on the fabric image called ccenv/baseos (golang), and the peer plant the code in the image to operate.

Comment: The v2.x version performs the pacakge process. If your problem is that you can't find the .so file in pacakge, there are two ways.
1. The .so file must be included in the package. Because the packaging process takes place within the peer, you must ensure that the .so file is included in the packaging process within the peer.

Comment: 2. Plant the .so file in the fabric-ccenv / fabric-baseos docker image or container. When the code runs in the virtual environment, you can put the .so file on the docker image or container so that you can find the library. This process may seem simple, but if multiple organizations/peers exist in a distributed environment,
The changed image must be distributed separately.